# Как узнать все приложения вконтакте, которые имеют доступ к моему аккаунту?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я удалил все приложения вконтакте с моей страницы. Но когда авторизуюсь с других сайтов- то авторизация проходит , то-есть те приложения всё так же имеют доступ к моим данным.
Где увидеть список этих приложений и какие у них права?
По-идее так может висеть приложение и сливать дяде мои данные и хотелось бы в этом разобраться.

Comment: Конечно имеют доступ. Вы когда на сайте включали приложение - оно у вас запрашивало права и вы разрешали их. А списки приложений вконтакте и на других сайтах вообще никак не связаны. Это же настройки каждого сайта индивидуально. Это все равно что проткнуть шину у одной машины, в надежде, что проткнутся шины у остальных автомобилей

Comment: Попробуйте зайти в "Приложения", выбрать вкладку "Мои приложения" и ниже будет опция "Настройки" - насколько я понимаю там будет список приложений, которым разрешен доступ. Их можно удалить нажав "Убрать".

Comment: вот тогда встречный вопрос. Если я захожу на сайт.а мне прозрачный фрейм кидают с кнопочкой-я думаю жму на кнопку- а на самом деле над кнопкой подставили левое приложение и кнопку согласия к нему. Я жму кнопку.но в реальности даю согласие на слив моих данных. Как вот только потом мне произвести чистку от подобного слива информации...

Comment: @RakzinRoman ничего не нажимайте)) и больше не оплачивайте интернет, на всякий случай))

Comment: не-ну это понятно конечно. Я про то.что любой может нахватать прозрачный фрейм даже и не думая об этом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Список всех приложений, которым вы разрешали доступ вы можете найти по [этой ссылке](https://vk.com/apps?act=settings). Что бы узнать, какие права имеет приложение, достаточно нажать на «Настроить» справа от названия приложения.

Comment: О...спасибо. То что надо. Как раз задал вопрос  . Если я захожу на сайт.а мне прозрачный фрейм кидают с кнопочкой-я думаю жму на кнопку- а на самом деле над кнопкой подставили левое приложение и кнопку согласия к нему. Я жму кнопку.но в реальности даю согласие на слив моих данных. Как вот только потом мне произвести чистку от подобного слива информации...

Comment: Это же просто приложения, а нужен список ботов и скриптов. Всех у кого есть API ключ

Comment: @ВасинЮрий, собственно, в момент написания ответа небыло ботов и приложений сообществ, а вся информация о desktop/iframe приложениях была в одном месте. В комментарии ниже есть актуальная ссылка, https://vk.com/settings?act=apps

Answer (score 2):

После редизайна список всех приложений, которым вы разрешили доступ к своему аккаунту, переехал в [Настройки > Настройки приложений](https://vk.com/settings?act=apps).